# GIT --- push everything to remote server, but with only with one log entry

Tags: git, gitlab

I am making changes to a project on my machine and do several commits in the process. However, when pushing to the remote server, I want all changes to be sent but with only **one** log entry.

That is, locally I have `commit1`, `commit2`, `commitN`. When I push it to the remote server, I only want it to show the `commitN` in history but still push all changes.

Is that possible?

Comment: I tried both `git rebase -i <hash-of-the-last-commit-before-commit1>` and `git rebase -i HEAD-N` where `N` is the number of commits to rebase. Thanks Sergey K. and Simon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase -i <hash-of-the-last-commit-before-commit1>`

An editor will open with a list like:

```
pick commit1
pick commit2
pick commitN
```

Edit the lines this way:

```
reword commit1
fixup commit2
fixup commitN
```

Save and exit your editor.

An editor will open once again - just type in the desired name of your final commit.

Now you can push your single commit to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an an interactive rebase where you squash the commits.

```
git rebase -i <commit>
```

Where  is the parent of the last commit you want to be included when you push.
Running this command will then let you choose which commits you want to squash into one.
Assuming that the commits you want to squash are the 10 last commits you would do this

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```